# Xpath for total absence of specific attribute-value in node

Tags: xml, xpath

Given a node with an undefined amount of child nodes, I want to find out whether there is a "total absence" of a certain attribute-value pair for all those child-nodes. I can query for this *absence condition* for single child-nodes like this:

```
//node[@some_attribute='some_value' and //node[@some_other_attribute!='value_of_interest']]
```

But that will match the absence of "any" child node and not necessarily all of them. Is there a way to do this for all of them? If necessary, I can achieve this outside of Xpath as well, but this would probably cripple performance

EDIT1:
An example XML would be this:

```
<xml>
    <node id='1' attr1='value'>
        <child id='1' attr2='foo' />
        <child id='2' attr2='bar' />
        <child id='3' attr2='bar' />
    </node>

    <node id='2' attr1='value'>
        <child id='4' attr2='bar' />
        <child id='5' attr2='bar' />
        <child id='6' attr2='bar' />
    </node>
</xml>
```

With this query:

```
//node[@attr1 and //child[@attr2!='foo']]
```

I can extract a node where *any one* child node has a value for *attr2* which is inequal to 'foo', but I need *all* child nodes of a node to be inequal to that value.

So the desired query would retrieve *node* with *id=2*, but not *node* with *id=1*.

I hope this clarifies things.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Comment: You really need to rephrase your question. Please state your problem in terms of an input XML document (which you need to _show_), your attempted path expression - and the exact output you expect from that expression (show it, too). Thanks.

Comment: I edited my question. Apologies! Hope the clarifies the question adequately

Comment: Much better, now your question is answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should try this way:

```
//node[@attr1 and count(.//child[@attr2='foo'])=0]
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I don't mean to be self-appraising, but this answer should not be the accepted one. There is no implication that `attr1` plays any role for the selection. Also, using `.//` is unnecessary, since those elements are immediate children of the context node.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it not as all child elements satisfying a condition, but as no child element *not* satisfying the condition.

```
//node[not(child/@attr2 = 'foo')]
```

which means

```
//node                               Select `node` elements anywhere in the document
[not(child/@attr2 = 'foo')]          but only if there is no child element called
                                     `child`, which has an attribute `attr2` whose
                                     value is "foo".
```

and the output is

```
<node id="2" attr1="value">
  <child id="4" attr2="bar"/>
  <child id="5" attr2="bar"/>
  <child id="6" attr2="bar"/>
</node>
```

---

If this is your actual document structure, use

```
/xml/node[not(child/@attr2 = 'foo')]
```

and if the name of the child elements of `node` does not matter, use

```
//node[not(*/@attr2 = 'foo')]
```